# Android glTexSubImage2D with GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES problem (OpenGL + OpenCV + CameraX)

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, android-camerax

I am writing an app utilizing CameraX to capture the camera feed, OpenCV to modify the frames and the OpenGL to render them on a `GLSurfaceView`.

My current approach was to render the original frames from CameraX, construct a pixel buffer, an OpenCV `Mat`, use `glReadPixels` to copy the pixel buffer (`ByteBuffer`) into the `Mat`, then process it, write the pixel buffer from `Mat` back to the pixel buffer and then render it onto the texture with `glTexSubImage2D`.

The problem is, CameraX enables me to access the frame data via `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES`, which - as per OpenGL's documentation - does not allow for `glTexSubImage2D` to modify the texture and my current approach, using the code below, does not work and continously throws `W/OpenGLRenderer: [SurfaceTexture-1-25873-0] bindTextureImage: clearing GL error: 0x500`, which is expected as says the documentation. Is there an alternative way to copy the buffer into `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` after OpenCV processing? Another thing I can think of is to copy the texture into `GL_TEXTURE_2D` and then use `glTexSubImage2D`, although I have no idea how to do that. Maybe someone knows another approach that would allow me to achieve the goal?

My code:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    GLES20.glClear( GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    if(this.resolutionSet) {
        surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();

        GLES20.glUseProgram(hProgram);

        int ph = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(hProgram, "vPosition");
        int tch = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(hProgram, "vTexCoord");
        int th = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(hProgram, "sTexture");

        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, hTex[0]);
        GLES20.glUniform1i(th, 0);

        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(ph, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 2, pVertex);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(tch, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 4 * 2, pTexCoord);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(ph);
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(tch);

        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, this.img.cols(), this.img.rows(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.imgBuff);

        img.put(0, 0, this.imgBuff.array());

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, img.toString());

        Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGRA);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img, img, Imgproc.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY);

        this.imgBuff.clear();
        img.get(0, 0, this.imgBuff.array());

        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, GL_RGBA, img.width(), img.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
        GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, 0, 0, 0, img.width(), img.height(), GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, this.imgBuff);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }

    GLES20.glFlush();
}
```

and the code initializing texture:

```
    hTex = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures ( 1, hTex, 0 );
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, hTex[0]);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you are replacing the entire image and uploading "normal" RGBA data from the application, why does this need to be a `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` type at all? Just use a normal `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

Comment: This might work; can you please advise me, possibly with some code, on how to initialize the new texture, clear the currently rendered pixels and render the new texture to screen?